# Consolidating integers within Ruby (on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, consolidation

I have a class which contains two integers (a and b) and a reference to an entity.

I want to be able to report back on the sum of all the a's and b's within the class.

E.g. I might have three records:

```
Entity    1  2  3 
a         5  9  3 
b         8  1  2
```

I want my consolidated result for a to be 17, and for b 11.

I'm interested in view on the best approach to this.  Now I could sum everything on the fly, but if there are lots of records that might be slow.

Or I could maintain a fake entity which contains the consolidated result and is updated each time any of the other objects are update.

Or I could have a different class for consolidated date?

All thoughts appreciated.

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a class method, something like:

```
def self.consolidated_a
  if @@cache_invalid
    @@cached_a = all.collect(0) { |sum, x| sum + x.a }
  end
  @@cached_a
end
```

If you want it cached, you could have a class variable called `@@cache_invalid` for example, and set this to true any time `a` or `b` change. Then you could check this, and return a cached value if false, and run the code above if true (I've now edited the code to include this change).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to track this information in the class. For example, suppose we have a number of FruitBaskets that may contain any number of `apples` and `bananas`. At any moment we want to know the total number of apples and bananas in all the baskets.

```
module FruitCounter
  attr_accessor :apples, :bananas

  def apples; @apples ||= 0; end
  def bananas; @bananas ||= 0; end
end

class FruitBasket
  class << self
    include FruitCounter   # Keeps track of the total for all FruitBaskets.
  end

  include FruitCounter

  def apples=(v)
    d = v - self.apples       # Note the difference.
    @apples = v               # Set the new value for this instance.
    self.class.apples += d    # Adjust the total by the difference.
  end

  def bananas=(v)
    d = v - self.bananas
    @bananas = v
    self.class.bananas += d
  end
end
```

Let's see it in action:

```
first = FruitBasket.new
 => #<FruitBasket:0x97be6f8> 
first.apples = 10; first.bananas = 15

FruitBasket.apples
 => 10 
FruitBasket.bananas
 => 15
```

So far, so good. How about another basket?

```
second = FruitBasket.new
 => #<FruitBasket:0x97b28e4> 
second.apples = 30; second.bananas = 20

FruitBasket.apples
 => 40 
FruitBasket.apples == first.apples + second.apples
 => true
```

And now let's modify the contents of the first basket:

```
first.apples = 3
 => 3 
FruitBasket.apples
 => 33
FruitBasket.apples == first.apples + second.apples
 => true
```

There you go!

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways you might choose from:

1. compute the sum of `a` and `b` eagerly, always when any of these change
2. compute lazily, only when someone needs the consolidated value

You should know which model of the above fits your needs more. I would put the eager way the following way:

```
class ABCounter

  @consolidated_apples = 0
  @consolidated_pears = 0

  class << self
    attr_accessor :consolidated_apples, :consolidated_pears
  end

  attr_accessor :apples, :pears
  def initialize
    @apples = 0
    @pears = 0
  end

  def apples=(x)
    ABCounter.consolidated_apples += x - @apples
    @apples = x
  end

  def pears=(x)
    ABCounter.consolidated_pears += x - @pears
    @pears = x
  end
end
```

The lazy way should go through all created instances of `ABCounter` and sum up the values of `a` and `b`.